# Error message to set iPhone/IPad ID in Facebook setting

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

We'd like to start promoting an app which just passed review (not released). 
As we put our **iPhone/IPad ID**, it shows

> "Having error to get your iPhone store ID from App store."

We tried to put "0" and "blank", but it still have error message.

Should I just ignore this message? Does it mean anything we should fix?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This ID should be relevant if you run App Install ads, it is the ID used to display/link to the App in the iOS App Store. Once your app is live on the store, pop the ID in there and it should save just fine.

If the ID is missing, there would be no way to link to your app in the iOS App Store.